# using backslash as string delimiter in python

Tags: python, delimiter

I want to split a string obtained from input by using `\` as delimiter in python. I saw a few answers which asked to put `r` before the string. I'm not sure how to do so in this case.

Here is the code:

```
import re
dob = input("Please enter the string ")
-> Please enter the string : 11\15\1995
sep = re.split('\\',dob)
```

expected output:

```
sep = ['11','15','1995']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **string.split** method

```
dob = r"11\15\1995"
print dob.split("\\")
```

**Output**:

```
['11', '15', '1995']
```

To get raw input use:

```
dob = raw_input("Please enter the string ")
if "/" in dob:
    print dob.split("/")
else:
    print dob.split("\\")
```

Comment: How does that answer the problem with `input()` ?

Comment: @StephenRauch;sorry I dnt undestand? OP is asking a way to split the input string by "\"

Comment: I want to get the input from the user. In that case how do I add r.

Comment: So show an example with input.  Or at least explain what you are doing.

Comment: import re
dob = input("Please enter the string : ")
--->     Please enter the string : 11/15/1995              //prompting to enter input
sep = re.split('/',dob) 

here the output is sep =['11','15','1995]

how do I do the same with backslash \

Comment: @rakesh I tried raw_input doesn't work with python 3

Comment: @Manoj; raw_input() was renamed to input() in python3